# Insert snippet until end of line in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, snippets

I'm trying to add a comment snippet in Visual Studio Code that should add dashes until the end of the column, however depending on the indentation the amount of dashes should be different. The snippet should generate the following:

```
//--------------------------------------------------
// | <- cursor here

  Indented code 
  //------------------------------------------------
  // | <- Cursor here
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Select the code and press `Ctrl + /`.

Comment: That just removes the comments. I.E

//------------ becomes
--------------